# Android NDK throwning signal SIGSEGV: invalid address after getting GoogleSignInClient in Activity via JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm developing an add-on to the Android port of the LÖVE 2D game framework to provide connectivity to Google Play Games Services from the games code. The most part of the framework is written in C++. It features a LuaVM with simplified bridges to SDL2 to access anything it needs.

To access Google Play Games Services from the Lua code that is running in the LuaVM, I have to add a native C++ module that contains entry points and wrapper classes. From there I redirect calls into the android.cpp from which I have to use the JNI to access the functions in my main Activity, since I have to sign in the player using the Java package `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin`.

This bridge works as expected. When the app is loading I initialise it like so:

**love2d-rich-android/love/src/jni/love/src/modules/mobsvc/config_MobSvc.h:**

```
static const bool MOBSVC_REQUIRED = false; // Force login into Google Play Games Services
```

**love2d-rich-android/love/src/jni/love/src/modules/mobsvc/MobSvc.cpp:**

```
MobSvc::MobSvc()
{
    love::android::mobSvcInit(MOBSVC_REQUIRED);
}
```

^- The module will be constructed on start of the app.

**love2d-rich-android/love/src/jni/love/src/common/android.h:**

```
void mobSvcInit(bool required);
```

**love2d-rich-android/love/src/jni/love/src/common/android.cpp:**

```
void mobSvcInit(bool required)
{
    bool inp1 = required;

    JNIEnv *env = (JNIEnv*) SDL_AndroidGetJNIEnv();
    jobject activity = (jobject) SDL_AndroidGetActivity();
    jclass clazz (env->GetObjectClass(activity));

    jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "mobSvcInit", "(Z)V");
    jboolean jinp1 = (jboolean) inp1;
    env->CallVoidMethod(activity, methodID, jinp1);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(activity);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);
}
```

**love2d-rich-android/love/src/main/java/org/love2d/android/RichGameActivity.java:**

```
public void mobSvcInit(boolean required) {
    // Specify if skipping of the login should be impossible.
    mobSvcRequired = required;

    // Determine if Google Play Games Services is installed on the device.
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean isKindle = (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Amazon") && Build.MODEL.equals("Kindle Fire")) || Build.MODEL.startsWith("KF");
    try
    {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(!isKindle ? "com.android.vending" : "com.amazon.venezia", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        String label = (String) info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);
        mobSvcAvailable = (label != null && !label.equals("Market"));
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        mobSvcAvailable = false;
    }

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mobSvcSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    Log.d("RichGameActivity","Play Games Services initialised.");
}
```

The code will pass, it will be executed. However the line `mobSvcSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);` causes it to crash on `ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, s);` in the function `Android_JNI_GetNativeWindow` in the file `love2d-rich-android/love/src/jni/SDL2-2.0.5/src/core/android/SDL_android.c`, afterwards, which is a JNI operation done by the SDL2 framework:

[image: Illustrating signal SIGSEGV: invalid address]

If the line is removed, everything keeps running without issue. For closer inspection the repository is available here: https://bitbucket.org/MartyMaro/love2d-rich-android/src/c5ad59b16a8b7f9fcc267a9f56e03de959c30b05/?at=MobSvc

I think this issue is not SDL2 related tho, because in a later step I went ahead and tried to make sure the code is called on the UI thread. Without digging to much into how the LuaVM and the LÖVE framework work, I've implemented the bridge for the module, so I can trigger the code above from Lua itself. So, the way things are called is the same, however the execution of the code is way later when the VM is already running and all the LÖVE modules are initialised and the code is executed in the UI thread for sure.

Now the exception is in the NDK bundle's jni.h (`~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/jni.h`):

[image: Illustrating signal SIGSEGV: invalid address #2]

The fault address seem to be the same and JNI (so the NDK) plays a role in both cases, so I believe getting the sign-in client of Google causes the NDK to fail on the next JNI operation. I need a proper way to handle this situation without causing any issues. I'm glad for anything ideas how to solve this issue.

Comment: `0xdeadd00d` is just the address that `jvmAbort` writes to in order to trigger a crash. Perhaps something you call in `mobSvcInit` throws an exception that doesn't get caught anywhere? You can check in your native code with `ExceptionCheck` and `ExceptionDescribe`.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for clarification. You are right, see my answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So I moved my code to the onStart of my Activity to get rid of the whole NDK dependency just to find out that I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception on runtime. After playing around I saw that I implemented an older version of auth in my gradle files.

Changed it to the recent one in my gradle file:

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

And the exception was not thrown. After that my JNI call does work. It turns out the exception was just higher in my stack and the NDK cannot handle such exception properly, so I just get a common invalid address exception.

If you have similar issues, try to get the latest libs before you try something else.